# there are $2n$ boys, $5n$ girls. they have to do their homework by group of $7$ , in each group $2$ boys and $5$ girls.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $2n$ boys, $5n$ girls. they have to do their homework in groups of $7$ , in each group $2$ boys and $5$ girls. in how many way you can make $7$ groups if the order between the groups and inside didn't matter?
the answer is: $\frac{(2n)!(5n)!}{(5!)^n(2!)^nn!}$
Why there is a division by $(2!)^n(5!)^nn!$

Answer (score 1):

The formula is as follows :

- $(2n)!$ for the number of ways you arrange boys overall (imagine in a straight line)
- $(5n)!$ for the number of ways you arrange girls overall

Now you need to divide by the number of arrangements in each groups :

- Each group has $5$ girls and their order doesn't matter. Since you have $5!$ ways of rearranging them you need to divide by $(5!)^n$ because you have $n$ groups.
- Similarly for boys, you divide by $(2!)^n$.

What I just did is I took those lines of boys and girls and I split them into all possible groups of $5$ and $2$ possible.

- Finally order of groups doesn't matter so you need to divide by $n!$ that's the number of ways you can rearrange $n$ groups.

So finally : $$\frac{(2n!)(5n!)}{(5!)^n(2!)^nn!}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably mean $n$ groups, not 7 groups.

One way to describe an arrangement is to put all the girls in a certain order, and all the boys in a certain order. Then the first two girls will work with the first five boys, the second two girls with the second five boys, etc.

There are $(2n)!$ ways to order the girls, and $(5n)!$ ways to order the boys. If the order of  the boys and girls in each group, as well as the order of the groups, mattered, then the answer to the question would be $(5n)!(2n)!$.

However, you count equivalent arrangements multiple times in this way. How many times do you count what is essentially the same arrangement? Well, there are $n!$ ways to order the $n$ groups. Also, within each group, there are $5!$ ways to order the boys, so there are ${(5!)}^n$ ways to order *all* the boys (in all the groups). Similarly, there are ${(2!)}^n$ ways to order all the girls. So what is in essence the same arrangement has been written down ${(5!)}^n{(2!)}^n n!$ times.

To obtain the number of inequivalent arrangements, you must divide the number of possible descriptions of an arrangement, $(5n)!(2n)!$, by the number of times each arrangement is counted, which is ${(5!)}^n{(2!)}^n n!$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we're lining the boys up and counting off by twos, and lining up the girls and counting off by fives.  The first group of boys works with the first group of girls, the second with the second, and so forth.

First group the boys off into groups of $2$.  There are $(2n)!$ ways to line them up.  We need to divide by $(2!)^n$ ways to arrange the boys within the groups (each of the $n$ groups can be arranged in $2!$ ways).  Label these groups $B_1 ... B_n$.

Now group off the girls.  There are $(5n)!$ ways to line them up, divided by $(5!)^n$ ways to arrange the girls within the groups.  Label these groups $G_1 ... G_n$.

Now, the extra factor of $n!$ comes from the fact that we can pick entire groups in this many ways.  Let's consider $n=3$.  We have groups $B_1, B_2, B_3, G_1, G_2, G_3.$  What if we picked all of the boys in $B_1$ last, and all of the boys in $B_3$ first, and all of the girls in $G_1$ last, and all of the girls in $G_3$ first?  The groups would have ended up exactly the same.  There are $n!$ ways to get the same $n$ sets of $2$ boys and $n$ sets of $5$ girls into exactly the same groups together.

So this means we have the total as being:

$$\frac{(5n)!}{(5!)^n} \frac {(2n)!}{(2!)^n} \frac {1}{n!}.$$